# Objective-c the init/initialize method

Tags: objective-c, initialization

I don't understand some cases :

1)

```
  +(void)initialize {

        if(self == [Bicycle class]) // Make sure it's not executed more than once
        _defaultMark = @"Unbranded product";

   }
```

I understand that this method is the first method called. But I don't understand why it permits to be sure that's not executed more than once ? After one execution , the self is always equal to Bicycle class in this case, non ?

2)

```
if(self = [ super init])
```

Can someone explain me clearly why it's really necessary to do it in the init or initWithSomething method ?

3) A HS question

```
@protocol StreetLegal <NSObject>
```

What if we don't use  avec the protocol name ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in case 1) `self` points to the `Class` object.
In the case 2) `self` points to the instance object.

`+(void)initialize` is guaranteed that it is called only once per `Class` (is the `Class` initializer). This is ensured by the framework/language.

I think that the `initialize` you posted is in some base class. If it is in the base class, than the `initialize` is called also for the descendent classes. In this way you ensure that the if-then is executed only for the `Bicycle` class. But.. I think that a better design can be achieved...

EDIT:

point 2). It is necessary because you have to call explicitly the initializer of your parent class.

point 3) I don't understand your question...

Comment: so it's really necessary to do if(self == [Bicycle class]) ?

Comment: I think that the `initialize` you posted is in some base class. If it is in the base class, than the `initialize` is called also for the descendent classes. In this way you ensure that the `if-then` is executed only for the `Bicycle` class.

Answer (score 0):

1) This method is called once per class - suppose you have

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@end

@implementation Foo
+ (void) initialize { .... };
@end

@interface Bar : Foo
@end

@implementation Bar
@end
```

In this case the same method will be called the first time `Foo` is used and when `Bar` is used the first time it would be called again. So the condition `if (self == [Foo class])` ensures to execute the body only once.

2) constructors can assign to `self`... and can return `nil`... so you should check

Answer (score 0):

Most of your init methods will look like this:

```
if ((self = [super init]) != nil)
{
}

return self;
```

First, you **must** call an init method of the superclass, or your object will not be initialised properly. Second, the superclass can return a different object, so you **must** assign the result to self, and third the superclass can return nil, so you **must** check that it isn't nil.

In your own initialisers, you will yourself set self to nil and return nil if your init method discovers that the object cannot be initialised properly.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

Is nicely answered in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize)

> The superclass implementation may be called multiple times if subclasses do not implement initialize—the runtime will call the inherited implementation—or if subclasses explicitly call [super initialize].

For example, if you override `+initialize` in class `A` and then you create a subclass `B` of `A` without overriding `+initialize`, then the method `+[A initialize]` will be called once for class `A` and once for class `B`. The class equals check is there to avoid the block to be called multiple times.

Question 2:

Again, you will find lots of information in the documentation. You want to call `[super init]` because you need the superclass initializer to run (otherwise the superclass structures wouldn't be initialized properly). The assignment to `self` is necessary because you don't always know what will be returned. In case of an unexpected error, you should expect a `nil` returned and check accordingly.

Question 3:

You are declaring a protocol which itself inherits from another protocol. `NSObject` isn't only a root class, there is also a root protocol called [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html). You don't have to use it, of course. However, when you then declare a variable as `id<MyProtocol>` without `MyProtocol` being a subprotocol of `NSObject`, you won't be able to call `NSObject` protocol methods on that variable.